# Change Row Label Start Index (vertical header) in QtableView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview

While displaying data, on a QTableView , due to an internal reason, i cannot display the first row and hence have to hide it, using

```
(qtableobj)->hideRow(0);
```

The problem is that, now the row labels start from 2.

[image]

How is it possible to start the index from 1, while keeping the first row hidden ?

Thanks.

Comment: What if introduce `QSortFilterProxyModel` that will filter the first row?

Comment: yes, i understand that it filters data between model and view, i am ok with it as long as the data in the model is not changed , and of course not much rework is to be done....Can you show a demonstration of how is done ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to involve the `QSortFilterProxyModel` that will filter out the first row in your model.
The code could look like:

```
class FilterModel : QSortFilterProxyModel
{
[..]
protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex & sourceParent) const
    {
         QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
         if (index.row() == 0) // The first row to filter.
             return false;
         else
             return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);
    }
}
```

Finally you need to set this model to your table view:

```
QTableView *table = new QTableView;
MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel;
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new FilterModel;

proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
table->setModel(proxyModel);
```

**UPDATE**

Since the issue is in how the header view displays row numbers, here is the alternative solution which based on special handling of header data in the model:

```
class Model : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    [..]
    virtual QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            if (orientation == Qt::Vertical) {
                // Decrease the row number value for vertical header view.
                return section - 1;
            }
        }
        return QAbstractTableModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
    }
    [..]
};
```

Set up the table view with the hidden first row.

```
QTableView *table = new QTableView;
Model *sourceModel = new Model;
table->setModel(sourceModel);
table->hideRow(0);
table->show();
```

Comment: sorry, did not test properly yesterday, i subclassed QProxymodel, and followed the above steps..i face the same problem, row 1 is hidden but the row numbering starts from two

Comment: Thanks...i solved this another way, but the answer looks right, and should work :)